# Elasticsearch querying multiple indices while limiting the fields of one index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have an `Autocomplete` class with a results method that queries two different models to return data. It partially works great, but with one major issue.

```
  def results
    Searchkick.search @query, index_name: [Location, DiveCenter]
  end
```

I need to limit the hits returned from the index `DiveCenter` because of the way I have the index set up. It's set up this way because a user will either click on a `DiveCenter` and be taken to the `DiveCenter` show page OR click on a location and be taken to `/search?(city | country)=value`.

```
  searchkick searchable: [:name, :city, :state, :country]
  def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      city: location.city,
      state: location.state,
      country: location.country
    }
  end
```

So basically, what I need is this:

```
  def results
    Searchkick.search @query, index_name: [Location, DiveCenter], fields: ['location.city', 'location.state', 'location.country', 'dive_center.name']
  end
```

Comment: how do you query elasticsearch (search or suggest)?

Comment: I query it via search

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't provide a way to limit results from a single index.

One approach is to filter the results in Ruby.

Another approach is to use [multi search](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#multi-search) to limit the results for dive centers.